# Handling "204 no content" in Spring-Integration

Tags: spring-integration

My `int-http:outbound-gateway` is returning **"204 no content"** . As a result my UI layer is failing because it is expecting a not null payload. Is there any way to handle this situation in Spring-Integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` does this:

```
if (this.expectReply) {
    ...
    AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> replyBuilder = null;
    if (httpResponse.hasBody()) {
        Object responseBody = httpResponse.getBody();
        replyBuilder = (responseBody instanceof Message<?>) ?
                            this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) responseBody) : this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(responseBody);

    }
    else {
        replyBuilder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(httpResponse);
    }
                replyBuilder.setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, httpResponse.getStatusCode());
    return replyBuilder.copyHeaders(headers).build();
    }
return null;
```

So, if you don't use `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` you definitely get some reply and there will be that `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header with the `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` as value.

As you see the `payload` of the message depends of the `httpResponse.hasBody()` and I guess in case of `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` there is really no `body`. So, payload is a full `ResponseEntity`.

Now, please, share more info how does it work for you? How do you get a `null` `payload`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The UI layer is checking for the `responseXML` (i.e. `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML`). Since it is becoming null, the UI layer is failing. I have even verified with `XMLHttpRequest.response ` , but it's also null. BTW, I am using IE browser. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Well, you have to share more config from controller to this gateway and back. Without more info it isn't clear on which step to help you. The browser doesn't matter here

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The service provider has provided a header Use-200-on-204-response using which 204 response will be converted to 200 . But it appears that the outbound gateway is not accepting the custom header. I am setting the header using `MessageBulider`. Am I missing anything in the configuration?

Comment: That's true. By default `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` deals only with the default HTTP headers. To make it process custom headers you should configure `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` to map desired custom headers: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks for your support.